# Django - Converting a Binary stream to an Image

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I am trying to obtain an image from a url and return it to the ModelAdmin to display it in a new column of the table.

I tried the following code in admin.py file:

`def new_field(self, obj):
    r = requests.get('https://abcd.com/image')
    return r.content`

The code is not giving me any error but it's returning a long binary string instead of the image itself.

How can I pass the image itself, or convert the binary content to an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need download image if you wont only show it.

```py
def new_field(self, obj):
    url = 'https://abcd.com/image'
    return '<img src="{}" />'.format(url)

new_field.allow_tags = True # it is important!!!
```

Comment: thank you but the thing is it displaying the whole string of ` <'img src=...` rather than displaying the image itself. i have set the allow_tags as well right after the function but still displaying a string instead of the image

Comment: It should works. Please show full code of you ModelAdmin class

Comment: actually when i used the mark_safe function it worked perfectly. I'm using Django 3.x  maybe that's why it's not working. but thanks for showing me how to actually get the image and return it. i didn't know that it can be this straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a [**`NamedTemporaryFile`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/core/files/temp.py#L70) here. For example:

```
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile

def store_image_from_source(self, obj):
    img = NamedTemporaryFile()
    r = requests.get('https://abcd.com/image')
    img.write(r.content)
    img.flush()
    file = File(img)
    obj.my_img_attr.save('filename.jpeg', file, save=True)
```

Here `'filename.jpeg'` is thus te name of the file, as if you would have uploaded a file with that name with a `ModelForm`.

Comment: my point here is not to actually save any image.. it's just to get it from the url and pass it to the admin template through setting the new field's value. is there a better way to achieve that? i'm a newbie to Django so please excuse my very basic questions.

Comment: @Alladin: well the problem is that Django only serves static/media files, and even only in development. For production, it does not serve such files *at all*. Then you will need to configure nginx/apache/...